# performance inpact of logging inside global action filters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, log4net

i created a global action filter to measure action execution time based on this answer [Measure Time Invoking ASP.NET MVC Controller Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353155/measure-time-invoking-asp-net-mvc-controller-actions)

i want to log the results using log4net.
i want to know if creating a logguer for each invocation has a performance impact.
i have a static instance of ILog inside each of my controllers defined as below

```
private static ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(CompteController));
```

can i access it directly inside the action filter?

or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I have used this same approach before.  Honestly, I don't see a REAL impact although you will technically incur "some".  If you are worried about it you can leverage a "fire and forget" logging approach so that it does not slow down execution of your code when logging.

Comment: You could create a singleton class that is instantiated when the application starts (global.asax or startup.cs) and then you only incur the instantiation cost only once?

Comment: @FrankO I need to have the logger created with the type of the controller class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to reduce logger overhead is create a single static logger for the whole application inside Global.asax.cs

```
public static ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MvcApplication));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could access the controller type within the action filter and instantiate the logger with the controller type (`typeof(filterContext.Controller.GetType())`). If you create a singleton and assign each new controller type logger in an array/collection, you should be able to access it on later requests.

If the logger for the controller does not exist within the singleton, then create a new one at that time. The cost of instantiating the new logger still exists but only when a new one is created.