# Identify execution time and Tracing of each API in ASP.NET WEB API and log to files using log4net using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

Currently , I am capturing execution time of each API using log4net and explicitly mentioning the start time and end time at the beginning and end of each API and writing into log file, as below

```
[HttpGet]
Public IHttpActionResult GetProducts()
{
    Log.info("API Execution Started at " + DateTime.Now());

    Var Products = UnitOfWork.GenericRepo.GetProducts();

    Log.Info("API Execution Completed at "+ DateTime.Now());

    Return Ok(Products);
}
```

Is there a better way to capture the execution time of each API and write that into a log file ? 
Also, Please provide me an insight on how to capture Tracing information of all APIs and writing that into different log files. For Example , Execution time of each API should be written into "ExecutionLog.txt" and Tracing infomration into "TracingLog.txt". I should also be able to enable or disable this features during run time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Measure Time Invoking ASP.NET MVC Controller Actions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353155/measure-time-invoking-asp-net-mvc-controller-actions)

Comment: Edited this to reflect the question in detail, other post does not provide more insight on achieving this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mahesh, You don't need to write it in each API. You can use ActionFIlter and ResultFilter and write a single code block to trace all actions in your API

Have a look at this 
https://jmperezperez.com/tracking-action-execution-time-in-asp-net-mvc/

Answer (score 1):

Use `Stopwatch` from `System.Diagnostics` namespace

see this for an example [Example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/stopwatch)

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

In, `System.Diagnostics` namespace, you have a class named `StopWatch`. You can use this for checking function execution time. Use the `Start()` and `Stop()` methods for finding the total execution time.

Here is a simple example taken from dotnet pearl website

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

// Begin timing.
stopwatch.Start();

// Do something.
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1);
}

// Stop timing.
stopwatch.Stop();

// Write result.
Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
```